# Access to Friend class in vb seems less restrictive than in c#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, inheritance

We have an existing vb.net project that contains a service reference and an abstract class.  One of the attributes of that class is the PortTypeClient to the service.  The access level of the service is Friend.

```vb
MustInherit Public Class BassyBase
    Private _ODQ As New ODQService.odqPortTypeClient

    Public Property ODQClient As Object
        Get
            ODQClient = _ODQ
        End Get
        Set(value As Object)
            _ODQ = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Sub New(url as String)

        Dim remoteAddress = New System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(url)
        Dim binding As New BasicHttpBinding
        binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = Int32.MaxValue
        ODQClient = New ODQService.dalsPortTypeClient(binding, remoteAddress)
        ODQClient.Endpoint.Binding.SendTimeout = New TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 30)
    End Sub

End Class
```

The people who are using VB have been using the base class for months without a problem. The base class is in its own DLL.  Child classes are being constructed in separate projects.  I attempted to inherit from the base class in my C# project and found that while the VB guys had access to ODQ as a ODQService.ODQPortTypeClient, that in C# I only had access to it as the Object that it is.

The C# behavior makes sense to me, as the service is a Friend (internal), and it is in a separate DLL.  Nothing outside the DLL *should* have knowledge of the service class types.  But, sense or not, I still need to use that base class.  Is there a way to tweak the base class's project so that a C# child class in a separate DLL can know what the type `ODQService.ODQPortTypeClient` is without making the service completely public?  Perhaps force the accessibility of the service a `Protected Friend`(Internal)? Somehow?

Comment: Since it is declared `As Object` that is how the VB consumer will be getting it too.  They might be using late binding or casting it to Type.  Not sure about the rest since we cant see the `ODQPortTypeClient` type

Comment: It looks to me as though the accessibility rules are different in VB.  Now that I am looking closer at the VB code, they routinely reference the service in the child as though it were public in the parent.

Comment: `[Friend] elements are accessible only from within the assembly that contains their declaration.`  and `Internal types or members are accessible only within files in the same assembly`. They are equivalent.  We cant see enough of anything to explain further.

Comment: This might be a stretch, but have the 'VB guys' created their own 'shadow' ODQPortTypeClient ?  (this would be a terrible thing to do, but I've seen this before).

Comment: I don't think so.  (I updated my original post to better reflect their base class.) Their child classes just use  ODQClient with no preamble. Certainly no shadow objects.  It just works.

Comment: There is still nothing there declared as Friend. `ODQClient` is a public property.  That code wont compile under Option Strict, if you fix that by making it `Property ODQClient As ODQService.odqPortTypeClient` (I made my own) it wont compile still because the property exposes a Friend type outside the namespace.   The VB code using the DLL is relying on late binding which means Option Strict is off in that project as well, or they have it set to ignore the error

Comment: Yeah.  I see what you are saying.  You should post that so I can check it as the answer.

Comment: When more than one person comments on a post, you need to use @ + username  (as in @Joe) to ping a specific person.  You get pinged for all comments because it is your post.   I happened to be tracking this question which is how I happened to see any of your replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From MSDN:

> [Friend] Specifies that one or more declared programming elements are
>   accessible only from within the assembly that contains their
>   declaration.
>
> The **internal** keyword is an access modifier for types and type
>   members. Internal types or members are accessible only within files in
>   the same assembly...

So, they are equivalent.  There is nothing in the posted code showing the `Friend` Class, but with `Option Strict On` this will not compile:

```vb
...
Public Property ODQClient As Object
    Get
        ODQClient = _ODQ
    End Get
    Set(value As Object)
        _ODQ = value            ' <<< compiler error  
    End Set
End Property
```

> Option Strict disallows implicit conversion from Object to ODQService.odqPortTypeClient

Well, that is easy to fix with:

```vb
Public Property ODQClient As ODQService.odqPortTypeClient
```

But that wont compile because the Public property attempts to "promote" the accessibility of `odqPortTypeClient`.

So, the DLL must be compiled using it  `As Object` and with `Option Strict Off`.  Any VB project using it, must be  relying on late-binding to access the properties and methods in the base class, which mean it *also* has `Option Strict Off`.  It also means that Intellisense cant/wont provide help on the underlying members because the Type is exposed `As Object` thru the property.

Honestly, if the underlying service is meant to be used by things which inherit that class, the service's access level is botched.

- [Friend (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/08w05ey2.aspx)
- [internal (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b.aspx)